# Asynchronous within non-void method

Tags: android, asynchronous, loopj

I'm using Android [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library to have asynchronous HTTP client. I need to set the `responseBody` to the image object's property like following but because of asynchronous, the return statement will be run instead and the image object is always null.

```
 public Image uploadImage(boolean async) {
        Image image = new Image();

        HttpClient.post(getFinalUrl(async), makeRequestParams(), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler
                () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                UploadResponse[] uploadResponses = GsonParser.getArrayFromGson(responseBody,
                        UploadResponse[].class);
                UploadResponse response = uploadResponses[0];
                String st = response.getContent();
                image.setImageAddress(st);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("injaro", error.getMessage());
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async methods don't work this way. You should pass them a callback object which will be called once the response is available.

So if you define a Callback interface like this:

```
public interface ImageCallback {
   void onImageReceived(Image image);
}
```

Then you could create 2 methods (one synchronous and one asynchronous) like this:

```
public Image uploadImage() {
...
}

public void uploadImageAsync(ImageCallback callback) {
...
}
```

At this point you'll just have to call the method you need - i.e. on button click listeners would call the async one (since you don't want to block the UI thread), but your background services could safely call the synchronous one.

Comment: You saved me and taught me a new thing, Thanks.